# Sending email using MailTo is not working on my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mailto

I have a web Page in my ASP.NET MVC application with a link called "Click here to request the access".

When the user clicks on this, Outlook New Email window is not showing.

Here is the Code using **mailto**:

```
<span><a href="mailto:Admin@XXXX.com?subject=Please give access to the user">Click Here</a> to request the access.</span>
```

Wondering.. am i missing any setting or anything?
Or is there any security thing that is stopping me.

Appreciate your time.

Thanks

Comment: +1 - I just noticed this in VS2010 with MVC3. Deploying my site to local IIS and running from there fixes the links, but clicking on them in debug mode has no effect.

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with the server. This is a client-side (browser) behavior. Do mailto links work for other websites? Is Outlook registered as the default mail software?